# SQL query to get matching records from Table1 and Table2 with a custom column showing 1/0 if data is present

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have several table related to multilingual Photo Galley like

- AlbumCategories
- AlbumName
- Photos
- PhotoDetails

Sample Table Structure of two table. I actually want a result set that will show me list of all records from `Photos` Table for particular `AlbumID` along with a custom column that will show `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on if particular PhotoID is present in the `PhotoDetails` Table

```
   Table: Photos
    PhotoID PhotoFile   AlbumID
    1       Photo1.jpg  7
    2       Photo2.jpg  7
    3       Photo3.jpg  5
    4       Photo4.jpg  5
    5       Photo5.jpg  7
    6       Photo6.jpg  7


Table: PhotoDetails
PDID        PhotoID     PDTitle     AlbumID     LanguageID
11      1       Photo 1     7       1
22      2       Photo 2     7       1
33      3       Photo 3     5       1
44      4       Photo 4     5       1


    DESIRED OUT PUT
    PhotoID PDTitle     AlbumID     DetailPresent
    1       Photo1      7       TRUE
    2       Photo2      7       TRUE
    5       Photo5      7       FALSE
    6       Photo6      7       FALSE
```

I tried something several JOIN based queries but could not get the desired result

```
SELECT pd.PhotoTitle, p.PhotoTN,p.PhotoCreatedOn, pd.AlbumID, ISNULL(p.PhotoID,NULL) AS Missing FROM AlbumPhotos p 
  JOIN AlbumPhotoDetails pd
  ON p.PhotoID = pd.PhotoID WHERE pd.AlbumID = 16
```

This query gives me the same result

```
 SELECT pd.PhotoTitle, p.PhotoTN,p.PhotoCreatedOn, pd.AlbumID, ISNULL(p.PhotoID,NULL) AS Missing FROM AlbumPhotos p 
  JOIN AlbumPhotoDetails pd
  ON p.PhotoID = pd.PhotoID WHERE pd.AlbumID = 16 
  OR  p.PhotoID  IN (SELECT PhotoID FROM AlbumPhotoDetails WHERE LanguageID = 1 AND AlbumID = 16)
```

Above query get me the result of matching based on `PhotoID`.  I am lost how i can actually achieve the desired result as shown in the above sample 'DESIRED OUT PUT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left outer join.

The table examples that you have shown doesn't make any sense, as there is no field to connect them, and the `PDTitle` values that you want in the result doesn't exist in the example data.

Assuming that there is a `PhotoId` field in the `PhotoDetails` table (like in the `AlbumPhotoDetails` table that you use in the query that you show), and that the `PhotoDetails` table contains the titles that you want in the result, you can do like this:

```
select
  p.PhotoId, d.PDTitle, p.AlbumId,
  case when d.PhotoId is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end
from Photos p
left join PhotoDetails d on d.PhotoId = p.PhotoId
where p.AlbumId = 7
```

Note that the title will be null where there are no corresponding record in the `PhotoDetails` table.

Comment: You are right i missed to add PhotoID in the PhotoDetails Table.. I will add that now